# Как получить JSON-строку

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

У меня есть `JSON` строка типа

```
{
    "countries":
    [
        [19,"Австралия"],
        [20,"Австрия"], 
        [5,"Азербайджан"],
        [21,"Албания"],
        [22,"Алжир"],
        [23,"Американское Самоа"]
    ]
}
```

Как получить эту строку в `String` массиве?

Comment: Весь `json` обрамляете кавычками, а кавычки внутри меняете с `"` на `\"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что вам нужно, следующий код парсит и кладет географические объекты в массив строк:

```
String json = "{\"countries\":[[19,\"Австралия\"],[20,\"Австрия\"],[5,\"Азербайджан\"],[21,\"Албания\"],[22,\"Алжир\"],[23,\"Американское Самоа\"]]}";
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(json));
    JSONArray countriesJson =  rootJson.getJSONArray("countries");
    for (int i = 0; i < countriesJson.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray countryJson = countriesJson.getJSONArray(i);
        result.add(countryJson.getString(1));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.d("TAG", result.toString()); //[Австралия, Австрия, Азербайджан, Албания, Алжир, Американское Самоа]
```